# How to change my code from a .live() to .on()

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I have a `live()` function in my jquery below:

```
$("#qandatbl td.weight input").live("change", calculateTotal);

function calculateTotal()
{
   var totalweight = hundred;
   $("#qandatbl td.weight input").each(function (i, elm){
        totalweight = totalweight - parseInt($(elm).val(), 10);
    });

    $("#total-weight").text(totalweight).append('%').css('font-weight', 'bold');
}
```

Now some people say that the `live()` function is slowing fading away and that is better to use the `on()` function. If this is true then how do I change the code above to `on()` function rather than a `live()` function? Is it important I don't use `live()` or does it not really matter that much?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

According to the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/live/):

> Rewriting the .live() method in terms of its successors is straightforward; these are templates for equivalent calls for all three event attachment methods:
>
> ```
> $(selector).live(events, data, handler);                // jQuery 1.3+
> $(document).delegate(selector, events, data, handler);  // jQuery 1.4.3+
> $(document).on(events, selector, data, handler);        // jQuery 1.7+
> ```

So in your case, if you're using jQuery 1.7+, it would be:

```
$(document).on('change', '#qandatbl td.weight input', calculateTotal);
```

Comment: Note also that ideally you won't use `$(document)` to set up your handler: although that is exactly what `.live()` does you're better off using the closest parent element to your actual target element(s) that you can as long as that parent exists at the time of your call to `.on()`. (Possibly your "#qandatbl" element?)

Comment: @nnnnnn has a very good point. This is, by the way, the main reason `live()` was replaced with `delegate()`. The reason `delegate()` is being replaced is probably just to unify all event binding: *"The new `.on()` and `.off()` APIs **unify** all the ways of attaching events [...]"* ([source here](http://blog.jquery.com/2011/11/03/jquery-1-7-released/), emphasis is mine).

Comment: Hi, sorry I tohught I ticked the best answer. Must of forgot to tick it but  Ihave ticked it now